# How to use PSP as controller in mupen64plus?

Tags: gamepad, emulation

I'm trying to use a Playstation Portable (PSP) as a controller in the mupen64plus emulator.

When I run the emulator, there is a message on the terminal saying that it detects a controller, but I cannot get it to work.

Here is what pops up on my terminal:

```
UI-Console: attached to core library 'Mupen64Plus Core' version 2.5.0
UI-Console:             Includes support for Dynamic Recompiler.
UI-Console:             Includes support for MIPS r4300 Debugger.
Core: Goodname: Legend of Zelda, The - Ocarina of Time (U) (V1.0) [!]
Core: Name: THE LEGEND OF ZELDA 
Core: MD5: 5BD1FE107BF8106B2AB6650ABECD54D6
Core: CRC: EC7011B7 7616D72B
Core: Imagetype: .v64 (byteswapped)
Core: Rom size: 33554432 bytes (or 32 Mb or 256 Megabits)
Core: Version: 1449
Core: Manufacturer: 43
Core: Country: USA
UI-Console Status: Cheat codes disabled.
UI-Console: using Video plugin: 'Mupen64Plus OpenGL Video Plugin by Rice' v2.5.0
UI-Console: using Audio plugin: 'Mupen64Plus SDL Audio Plugin' v2.5.0
UI-Console: using Input plugin: 'Mupen64Plus SDL Input Plugin' v2.5.0
UI-Console: using RSP plugin: 'Hacktarux/Azimer High-Level Emulation RSP Plugin' v2.5.0
Input: 0 SDL joysticks were found.
Input: N64 Controller #1: Forcing default keyboard configuration
Input: 1 controller(s) found, 1 plugged in and usable in the emulator
Input Warning: Couldn't open rumble support for joystick #1
Input Warning: Couldn't open rumble support for joystick #2
Input Warning: Couldn't open rumble support for joystick #3
Input Warning: Couldn't open rumble support for joystick #4
Input: Mupen64Plus SDL Input Plugin version 2.5.0 initialized.
Video: SSE processing enabled.
Video: Found ROM 'THE LEGEND OF ZELDA', CRC b71170ec2bd71676-45
Video: Enabled hacks for game: 'THE LEGEND OF ZELDA'
Video: Initializing OpenGL Device Context.
Core: Setting 32-bit video mode: 640x480
Video Warning: Failed to set GL_SWAP_CONTROL to 0. (it's 32)
Video Warning: Failed to set GL_DEPTH_SIZE to 16. (it's 24)
Video: Using OpenGL: Intel Open Source Technology Center - Mesa DRI    Intel(R) Pineview M x86/MMX/SSE2 : 2.1 Mesa 11.2.2
Audio: Initializing SDL audio subsystem...
Input Warning: Couldn't open rumble support for joystick #1
Input Warning: Couldn't open rumble support for joystick #2
Input Warning: Couldn't open rumble support for joystick #3
Input Warning: Couldn't open rumble support for joystick #4
Core: Starting R4300 emulator: Dynamic Recompiler
Core Status: Stopping emulation.
Core: R4300 emulator finished.
Core Status: Rom closed.
```

As you can see, mupen64plus does indeed detect a controller. So how can I make it work? I tried the command-line program, jstest-gtk, which usually works for mapping new controllers, but it doesn't detect the PSP. The PSP is connected to my computer via the auxiliary usb cable.

Oh and I have also tried with the PSP on and off--the result is the same--mupen64plus detects a controller but jstest-gtk does not.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated--has anyone gotten the PSP to work as a controller in mupen64plus?

Below is a sample from the  InputAutoCfg.ini file, which is filled with configurations for many controllers. I cannot find one for the PSP in it; is there something I could add to this file to make the PSP work?

```
[PLAYSTATION(R)3 Controller]
[Sony PLAYSTATION(R)3 Controller]
[SHENGHIC 2009/0708ZXW-V1Inc. PLAYSTATION(R)3Conteroller]
plugged = True
plugin = 2
mouse = False
AnalogDeadzone = 4096,4096
AnalogPeak = 32768,32768
DPad R = button(5)
DPad L = button(7)
DPad D = button(6)
DPad U = button(4)
Start = button(3)
Z Trig = button(10)
B Button = button(15)
A Button = button(14)
C Button R = button(13)
C Button L = axis(2-)
C Button D = axis(3+)
C Button U = button(12)
R Trig = button(11)
L Trig = button(8)
Mempak switch = 
Rumblepak switch = 
X Axis = axis(0-,0+)
Y Axis = axis(1-,1+)
```

Comment: @Rinzwind please see the above edits. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks good to me :(